# é shown as &eacute; after dom conversion in java

Tags: java, dom

I'm trying to convert a HTML String to a dom to make some dom level changes and converting it back to a String. The HTML is in French and characters such as é are shown as `&eacute;` is the converted String after transformation.

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

String modifiedContent = "";
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
transformer.transform(source, result);
modifiedContent = writer.toString();
```

"Résultats de recherche" is a string, after dom is converted to String, "`R&Atilde;&copy;sultats de recherche`" is the result.

I'm feeding this to an FOP processor to convert it to a pdf so, I need the characters in its original form.

Comment: Do you try to convert  é to  \u00E9 (Unicode presentation) take a look at this link may help you http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/unicode.html

Comment: `writer.toString()` prints `R&Atilde;&copy;sultats`?

Comment: @sp00m, yes, exactly

Comment: @stackMan10 See [this little snippet](http://pastie.org/10175289) I tried: I can't reproduce your error. Do you observe the same behavior? Note that the input HTML file I used is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @sp00m R&eacute;sultats is the result that I don't want ... "Résultats"  should be "Résultats" in the resultant string; for fop to process it. Yes, the &Atilde;&copy; is a different issue all together.

Answer (score 2):

It looks normal to me that DOMSource keeps the characters in html form.

You can probably use the [Jakarta library unescape html method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29) to convert back the html characters to regular strings.
In your case, you should just add this line:

```
String unescapedHtml = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(modifiedContent);
```

Make sure you add the proper [maven dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.1) to your project.

P.S. There seem to be a newer version of the library on maven central, but I could not find the associated javadoc.